# Recover email sended through exim?

Tags: email, centos, whm, exim

lost some important data from my server and I know that data was sended via email. I have root access and I need to recover those emails.

I looked into exim logs and I have the email ID, but when I use a command like:

```
root@server [/var/spool/exim/msglog]# exim -Mvh 1ZfRwk-003bDf-JB
```

Failed to open input file for 1ZfRwk-003bDf-JB-H: No such file or directory.

Logs looks like:

```
2015-09-25 08:17:50 1ZfRwk-003bDf-JB <= info@myserver.com U=username P=local S=7453 id=20150925121750.117390002 ...... etc
```

I am running WHM under centOS

Is possible recover sended mails?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No, You can not recover any mail which was send from your server. You can check your 1ZfRwk-003bDf-JB mail logs with the following command so that you can find out full logs of that mail.

```
grep 1ZfRwk-003bDf-JB /var/log/exim_mainlog
```